# Python: How can I initialise object in one module and use it in another

Tags: python, oop, python-import, pickle, python-object

my setup:
mod1.py:

```
class cars:
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.x = x
```

mod2.py:

```
import mod1
obj = mod1.cars(x,y,z)
```

mod3.py

```
from mod2 import obj
```

Now, what's happening is when I am importing obj in `mod3.py` init method of cars is getting executed. what I want it as obj is already initialised in `mod2.py`, mod3 should get already initialised instance and not create new one.
How can I do that in python

Comment: Why do you think a new one gets created?

Comment: Why aren't you using `from mod2 import obj`

Comment: Oh, I missed that, @Bazingaa. That probably explains it.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I tried printing message from __init__ method and that is executed on every import

Comment: @Bazingaa sorry that was a typo. I am importing it from mod2.py

Comment: It shouldn't be executed on _every_ import. Only on the _first_ import. Are you sure you just didn't see the first import when you ran `mod3.py`? It would then import `mod2`, instantiating an instance, printing a message. But subsequent imports of `obj from mod2` wouldn't lead to additional prints, I believe. Please post a [mcve] where you saw more than one instantiation.

Comment: @AndrasDeak by every import I mean every first import from different modules.

Comment: I tried your code, imported it from two separate modules, saw only one print from the `__init__`. Can't reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

> Now, what's happening is when I am importing obj in mod3.py init method of cars is getting executed.

Of course it is, that's what you told python to do. The first time a module is imported (in a given process), all the statements at the top level are executed. You create `obj` at the top-level of mod2, so the first time you import `mod2`, `mod1` is imported, then `mod1.cars(...)` is called, which calls `mod1.cars.__init__()`.

> what I want it as obj is already initialised in mod2.py, mod3 should get already initialised instance

That's exactly what happens. For the current process of course - objects don't live outside of a process (and are not shared between processes)

> by every import I mean every first import from different modules

As long as all those imports happens in the same process, `mod2.obj` will be created only once *for this process*. Of course if you have different processes, each process will have it's own instance of `obj` - as I said, objects only exist at runtime and are not shared between processes (hopefully).

The *only* case where you can have the same module imported twice is if your `sys.path` is messed up and allow a same module name to be resolved against two different qualified names AND you have one import using one qualified name and the other using the other qualified name - but this is a rather uncommon situation.