# use variable and function from class in one module in a function(not inside class) in other module python

Tags: python, python-3.6

Module1.py

```
class A:
  def __ init __(self):
     self.var1 = var1
     self.var2 = var2

  def method1():
    return X
```

Module2.py

```
import module1 as mod

if __name__ = "main":
    objA = mod.A()
    objA.method1()
```

Module3.py

```
import module1 as mod
 
def method3():
  #use var1 and method1 with same objA
```

Using python3.6
Please advice me how to use `var1`, `method1` in `method3`.

Comment: Well, `var1` is an ***instance*** attribute so you will need an instance of `A`. Try `print(A().var1)`

Comment: These are some basic OOP principles in Python that SO is not the place to learn. Consider going over [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) to get a grasp of the Python basics

Comment: Thanks,(edited question) but object of class in module2, and want to use var1 and method1 of module3.Please  advice me I am new to OOPS

Comment: Found similar question, but could not find appropriate answer.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53065812/python-how-can-i-initialise-object-in-one-module-and-use-it-in-another

Comment: As I told you in a previous comment, `var1` and `method1` are instance attribute's so you need to create an instance of `A`. If you meant to use the one defined in `module2`, then you can't use because it's protected under `if __name__ = "main":` (for unknown reasons). Simply move it outside the `if` and use it in `module3` as `module2.objA`